# Execute ffmpeg to Crop Audio in Qt

Tags: qt, audio, ffmpeg

I want to create an application which can be used to crop audio files using Qt.
I've successfully run ffmpeg via command line to do this using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -i C:\\test.mp3 -acodec copy C:\\test2.mp3
```

Then I tried to do this using Qt and my code below seems to work, but I can't find the output file (test2.mp3).

```
QProcess* process=new QProcess(this);
process->start("FFmpeg-N-49957-g8c95d17\\ffmpeg.exe",QStringList()<<"-t 30 -i C:\\test.mp3 -acodec copy C:\\test2.mp3");
```

Is there anything wrong with my code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you forgot to add 'waitForFinished()' line and it just doesn't have time to complete your task

```
QProcess process;
process.start("ffmpeg -t 30 -i C:\\test.mp3 -acodec copy C:\\test2.mp3");
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

Comment: I've tried your code above. The ffmpeg in my folder is an executable file. So I can't start it using ffmpeg command (I should specify its directory). And there seems to be a problem since process.start method requires at least two parameters.

Comment: nope, there is overloaded version of this function, which requires only one input parameter http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start-2

about folder:
process.start("FFmpeg-N-49957-g8c95d17\\ffmpeg.exe -t 30 -i C:\\test.mp3 -acodec copy C:\\test2.mp3");

will work just fine

Comment: it's working. thanks for your help. So I shouldn't use the second parameter.